# How would I go about printing text from a java program? (Java)

Tags: java, text, printing

I don't even know if this is possible and I highly doubt it is, but if you can, can you please tell me how?
I just want to know how to print some text from a printer.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to print text *to* a printer?

Comment: Please read the Java print API: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/print/package-summary.html.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html this may help you :)

Comment: Yes, I would like to print to a printer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintException;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;

import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies;

import javax.print.event.PrintJobAdapter;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobEvent;

public class PrintText {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws PrintException, IOException {

    String defaultPrinter = 
      PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService().getName();
    System.out.println("Default printer: " + defaultPrinter);
    PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

    // prints the famous hello world! plus a form feed
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream("hello world!\f".getBytes("UTF8"));

    PrintRequestAttributeSet  pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    pras.add(new Copies(1));

    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);
    DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

    PrintJobWatcher pjw = new PrintJobWatcher(job);
    job.print(doc, pras);
    pjw.waitForDone();
    is.close();
  }
}

class PrintJobWatcher {
  boolean done = false;

  PrintJobWatcher(DocPrintJob job) {
    job.addPrintJobListener(new PrintJobAdapter() {
      public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        allDone();
      }
      public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        allDone();
      }
      public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        allDone();
      }
      public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        allDone();
      }
      void allDone() {
        synchronized (PrintJobWatcher.this) {
          done = true;
          System.out.println("Printing done ...");
          PrintJobWatcher.this.notify();
        }
      }
    });
  }
  public synchronized void waitForDone() {
    try {
      while (!done) {
        wait();
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me, nothing happens... With message "printing done..." on console.

Comment: @benny, what is the default printer (from the console output) ?

Comment: sth like "Default printer: Dell 3110cn ..."

Comment: This is also not working for me. Should there be added some parameters for the printer? The example below works, but there is a swing popup.

Comment: This does not work. It shows in the console printing done but nothing printed at all. Please fix the issue.

Answer (score 7):

Here is something that is even easier.

```
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;

public class TestPrint {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws PrinterException {

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();

        textPane.setText("test text string - Hello World! Are you there?");

        textPane.print();

    }
}
```

**Output: popup**

[image]

Comment: This has never worked for me. The printer always prints a blank page when I attempt this.

Comment: This is working nice. But how to avoid the SWING GUI and silently print the text?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is write to a file and then you can use `Desktop` class to print it. for more infomation on desktop class go [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/desktop_api/)

```
here is the program


import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class abc {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("1.txt"));
        out.write("Hello this is a test");
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        File ff = new File("1.txt");

        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
      desktop.print(ff);

}
```

}

Comment: This works. But it prints 1.txt and page number in the printing. How to remove the file name and page numbers?

Answer (score -1):

Following Man o War's and bmargulies' comments, take a look at the [Java Tutorial Printing Lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html) and the [Java Print API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/print/package-summary.html).

(Primarily posting this answer in an attempt to either get this question some additional attention / competitive answers, or at the least, to simply remove this from the growing list of unanswered questions.)

Comment: Answers should contribute new info the problem, not restate other people's comments.

Comment: @james.garriss - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-to-do-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-instead-of-a would disagree with you.  Please note that most of the other answers - including the accepted one - were not yet posted here when I posted this.  I say, mission accomplished.