# Printing works on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, printing

I am developing a web application which prints a pdf file (from a ByteArrayOutputStream).
Here is the code:

```
PrintService service = null;
for (String printer : listPrinters){
    for( PrintService printService : printServices ) {
        Attribute[] attrs = printService.getAttributes().toArray();
        for (int j=0; j<attrs.length; j++) {
            String attrName = attrs[j].getName();
            String attrValue = attrs[j].toString();
            if (attrName.equals("printer-name")){
                if (attrValue.equals(printer)){
                    service = printService;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
try {
    InputStream fi = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());

    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    DocPrintJob printJob = service.createPrintJob();
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fi, flavor, null);
    printJob.print(doc, null);

} 
catch (Exception e1) {
    log.debug(e1.getMessage());
}
```

If I deploy the WAR in Tomcat 7 on a linux server, the document is well printed on the printer.
If I deploy the WAR in Tomcat 7 on Windows, I can see the document on the jobs queue of the printer, then it disappears as if the printing was finished, but nothing comes out of the printer.
I don't understand why. I am using JRE 1.8.0_74 on both systems.
I am developing under Linux

If  anyone can help me on this...

Thank you.

**[UPDATE]**
Same error when printing a simple txt file :

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/mytxt.txt");
Doc pdfDoc = new SimpleDoc(fis, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE, null);
DocPrintJob printJob = service.createPrintJob();
printJob.print(pdfDoc, new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet());
fis.close();
```

Comment: try calling `baos.flush()` and `baos.close()` before creating `InputStream` from the bytes of the `ByteArrrayOutputStream`

Comment: It doesn't work either. I have tried with  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/mypdf.pdf");, but same problem.

Comment: You could try avoiding autosense, by setting `DocFlavor` to `DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF`. However I think this means that printer has to have native support for PDF printing. You can also try `DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.PDF` avoiding `InputStream` creation.

Comment: Plot thinkens... Your drivers have to support PDF printing for all of the above to work. In Linux it is more common for drivers to support it. Please make sure your Windows drivers do support PDF printing. Perhaps update the drivers if newer versions do support it. 
This discussion has shed some light: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407459/silent-printing-of-pdf-from-within-java

Comment: Same problem with other Docflavor. The problems occurs also with a simple text file.

Comment: When I print to a PDF Creator printer, it works. But with the HP or a CANON printer, it doesn't (test with autosense docflavor).

Comment: I think you got it: the printer and the drivers have to allow for native PDF printing. PDF Creator does it - would be strange if it didn't. Make sure your printer drivers do support PDFs. When you say simple text file, do you mean `*.txt` ?

Comment: yes, a file called mytxt.txt for example. So that's why I think the problem may not come from the native PDF printing issue.

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198855/how-would-i-go-about-printing-text-from-a-java-program-java  and look at `PrintJobWatcher`. Seems reasonable to keep the process up before the printing is done. 

And with this suggestion I am out of ideas...

Comment: @user1260928 did you got any solution ? because im having the same problem.

Comment: I solved the issue by using Apache PDFBox.